# Playframework / Scala - Redirect not working

Tags: scala, redirect, playframework

I check to see if my sign in response is `Ok` (status 200), and if true then I want to redirect to a different URL, while clearing the session.

I've tried the following.

```
signIn.map {
 status =>
    if(status.header.status == OK) {
        Redirect("https://google.com/").withNewSession
    } else {
        logger.report("sign in response not OK")
        logger.error(status.toString())
        status
    }
}
```

I have a feeling that it might be something to do with Ok representing a status 200, and redirect representing a status 303.

The result of the above block of code is the else block.

Note: `signIn` is of type `Future[Result]` if that matters.

Any ideas why it doesn't work?

Comment: `Redirect` does work, so it need the complete `Action` code to be reviewed

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the success status from your sign in service is something else than 200. Maybe if you put additional information from the logger, we will know for sure.

The code looks weird though. I would rename status to signInResponse and in the else statement I would return Unauthorized instead of response from other service/server. This looks really bad.